# with sr.Microphone() as source not working

Tags: python, pyaudio

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()

try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('listening......')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print(command)
except:
    print("Sorry")
```

My output comes as Sorry. Why is not my sr.Microphone() working

Comment: Try temporarily removing the try except block so you can see the details of your exception.

Comment: change to `except Exception as e:`
    `print("Sorry", e)`